# redirect to a website in c

Tags: sockets, redirect

I am using the following code to redirect client request. But when doing the following the clients are not redirected. Its showing "Unable to connect" in the browser. I redirect the clients to port 8080 using iptables. And running the following executable to redirect. How to redirect the clients. Please provide solution....

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h> 

#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

char *reply = "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\nServer: Apache/2.2.3\nLocation: 
http://www.google.com\nContent-Length: 1000\nConnection: close\nContent-Type:  
text/html; charset=UTF-8";

char sendBuff[1025];
time_t ticks; 

listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff)); 

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(8080); 


bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); 

listen(listenfd, 10); 

while(1)
{
    connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL); 

printf("client connected\n");
    send(connfd, reply, strlen(reply), 0);

    close(connfd);
    sleep(1);
 }
 }
```

Comment: you need to send a Location: XXX in the header of http output and a status 301 (moved permanently)

Comment: how can i add that line. please provide code..

Comment: You need to create a valid HTTP response first, please google what a protocol requires minimum - in your case you are just sending an html body without http status and headers

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the example in [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Server_response) or [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) to construct a valid http response on the server side. Then, add your html body below it.

Minimum you would need is

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Length: XXXXX <- put size of the your html body 
 Connection: close
 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce the error that you see. You should provide more details (e.g., what kind of client, exact text of iptables rule). For my test, I did not set any iptables rule, and instead pointed the Firefox 12.0 browser directly to `localhost:8080`.

Splitting up your reply so that it is easier to read shows:

```
char *reply =
"HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\n"
"Server: Apache/2.2.3\n"
"Location: http://www.google.com\n"
"Content-Length: 1000\n"
"Connection: close\n"
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"
;
```

Although the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) specifies `\r\n` for line terminators, most clients will accept `\n` (you don't say which client you are using). But, three other glaring issues are that the last line is not terminated, the response itself is not terminated by a blank line, and you have a `Content-Length` header of `1000`, but no content. Any of these issues could be cause for a client to treat the response as invalid and ignore it.

```
char *reply =
"HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\n"
"Server: Apache/2.2.3\r\n"
"Location: http://www.google.com\r\n"
"Content-Length: 0\r\n"
"Connection: close\r\n"
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n"
"\r\n"
;
```

Reading farther into your code, you close the connection immediately after sending your reply without first reading the request. This might lead to an (albeit unlikely) race where you close the connection before the request is fully delivered to the server. Then, when the request does arrive, it will trigger a reset to the client, and the response could be dropped. So, you should add code to make the delivery of your reply more robust:

```
printf("client connected\n");
send(connfd, reply, strlen(reply), 0);
shutdown(connfd, SHUT_WR);
while (recv(connfd, sendBuff, sizeof(sendBuff), 0) > 0) {}
close(connfd);
```

Given that I cannot reproduce your issue with the response as it is, though, it is also possible that you did not set your iptable redirect rule properly.

Comment: I am running the code in port 8080. and I'm having a iptable rule to redirect the clients to the port 8080. So, whenever a client is connected that is redirected to this port and I'm running this redirector at the port 8080. So, the client is again and again hitting the port 8080 only. so its not getting redirected. Please provide me a solution to redirect properly..

Comment: @user1216216: Since you never provided the rule that you used, there is no way for me to tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080 

This is the rule i used to redirect to port 8080. Since I'm redirecting to this port all the requests are go through the port and in the given program i'm redirecting to some Website[www.google.com], that also go-through the port 8080. So, the client is loop in the port 8080.. then I'm not getting the redirected page in my browser.. Now tell me how to redirect the client to port 8080 and from port 8080 the client should be redirected to some other website..?.

Comment: @user1216216: You should probably use the `filter` table and the `INPUT` chain for your rule.