# HTTP Redirect using sockets

Tags: c++, http, sockets, redirect, network-programming

I have an application that binds special port on localhost and waiting for connection and HTTP request. For example, I start my app and write in browser:

> 127.0.0.1:12345/?data=message

and my application receives it and process (using winsock). My problem is: how to make redirect. When my app receives data I need client (in browser) to be redirected to special page on the internet (now client just see "page not found").

Sorry for my maybe stupid questions, I have never worked with sockets, requests, etc. before.

Comment: what is the actual use case? before you worry about how to redirect, you need to learn how to write a simple server using sockets.  Then you need to send a response with a 301 redirect header, that's the easy part.

Comment: it is connected with my previous question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387035/receive-get-request-through-sockets

Comment: Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982257/redirect-to-a-website-in-c

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add it in the HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://whatever.org/">
```

And set the http:// whatever.org/ to wherever you need it redirected

Comment: @user1944429 using sockets you canjust send the http header, no need to send it as html.

Comment: @DuXeN0N if you've solved it please post your answer for others who find this post